# Dreamweaver CS5 SVN Proxy Settings

Tags: svn, proxy, dreamweaver

The SVN within Dreamweaver works well when I have a direct internet connection. However, when I am at work, I must enter the proxy and port for the LAN as well as the username and password prompted from the browser. I am not sure how can I do this in Dreamweaver as I feel this is the reason SVN fails to work.

When I test the SVN in Dreamweaver, I get this error:

**Server and project are not accesible (175002)**

Help please!

Comment: I am having the same problem, but I am not attempting to use a proxy. What Protocol are you using in the Site Manager dialog > Version Control ? When I try HTTP, I get the error you are getting. When I try SVN, I get the same error plus: "Cannot connect to host xxx: connection refused". Did you figure out what was going on?